# Silverlight 4 ComboBox Rendering Problems

Tags: silverlight-4.0, combobox

I have a Static Resource that provides for a list of genders to be used as a DataSource to the ComboBox. When the combo box renders, there is no text/content in any of the ComboBoxItem's.

```
public class Gender
{
    public string code;
    public string description;
}

public class LookupTables
{

    public List<Gender> GenderList
    {
        get
        {
            List<Gender> g = new List<Gender>();
            g.Add(new Gender{code="M",description="Male"});
            g.Add(new Gender{code = "F", description = "Female" });
            return g;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the App.xaml entry making this a Applicaton wide static resource

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/> 
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <res:ResourceWrapper x:Key="ResourceWrapper" />
                <app:NotOperatorValueConverter x:Key="NotOperatorValueConverter" />
                <hlpr:LookupTables x:Key="LookupTables"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>                
</Application.Resources>
```

Here is the ComboBox Snippet that used this Static Resource

```
                <ComboBox Height="23" Name="comboBox1" Width="120" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource LookupTables},Path=GenderList}" 
                      SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged"
                      DisplayMemberPath="description"/>
```

Comment: I know this is not what you asked, but did you realize that you are creating a new instance of the list every time the property is accessed? Beyond the potential implications in performance, this may have side effects on the binding as well. Consider having a single instance that you initialize once and use many times.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It's because the Gender class need to have corresponding properties setters

```
public class Gender 
{ 
    public string code{get;set;} 
    public string description{get;set;} 
}
```